# Where is $e$ hidden in this sequence

Tags: integration, limits

Let $a_n$ be a sequence which is defined recursively as:

$a_0=c-1 \space $ $(c\in\mathbb{R})$

$a_n=na_{n-1}-1$

Alternatively, $a_n$ can be defined aswell as:

$a_n=cn!-\int_1^\infty x^ne^{1-x}dx$

Now, the task is to show, that:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=\begin{cases} -\infty & \text{for $c<e$} \\ 0 & \text{for $c=e$} \\ \infty & \text{for $c>e$} \end{cases}$

...with $e$ being Euler's number. I really didn't expect $e$ to be hiding in this sequence, but well, I guess math likes to be surprising. But where can I find it? I tried playing a little bit with the integral, and maybe somehow get to some $e$-ish expression, but sadly I wasn't able to find anything. Could you guys maybe give me a tip? Thanks in advance!

Oh, and there are tips given (which don't have to be proven) for this task:

$n!=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^1x^ne^{-x}dx=\int_0^1\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the sequence as

$$a_n = cn! - e\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx + \int_0^1 x^ne^{1-x}dx = (c-e)n! + \int_0^1 x^ne^{1-x}dx$$

You can take the limit of the right hand side now. The integral will always go to $0$ because $x^n\to 0$ for $x\in(0,1)$, so what dominates the behavior of this sequence is the factorial. If $c\neq e$, it runs away to the appropriate infinity.